# phpUnit installation on Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I follow this manual:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html
and when I run "\vendor\bin\simple-phpunit" (after "composer require --dev symfony/phpunit-bridge") on Windows, the result is:

```
PS C:\xampp7\htdocs\symfony\xliff_excel_converter> .\vendor\bin\simple-phpunit
Das Verzeichnis ist nicht leer.
symfony/yaml is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Package operations: 23 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing phar-io/version (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phar-io/manifest (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing theseer/tokenizer (1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/version (2.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/environment (3.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (2.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.5): Loading from cache
  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (5.3.0): Loading from cache
    Failed to download phpunit/php-code-coverage from dist: 
    The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems):
    ZipArchive::extractTo(C:\xampp7\htdocs\symfony\xliff_excel_converter\vendor\bin\.phpunit\phpunit-6.5/vendor/composer/18993172/sebastianbergmann-php-code-coverage-661f34d\tests\_files\Report\HTML\CoverageForClassWithAnonymousFunction/source_with_class_and_anonymous_function.php.html): 
    failed to open stream: No such file or directory
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (5.3.0): Cloning 661f34d0bd from cache


  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage.git via https, ssh protocols, aborting.

  - https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage.git
    fatal: destination path 'C:\xampp7\htdocs\symfony\xliff_excel_converter\vendor\bin\.phpunit\phpunit-6.5\vendor\ph
  punit\php-code-coverage' already exists and is not an empty directory.

  - git@github.com:sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage.git
    fatal: destination path 'C:\xampp7\htdocs\symfony\xliff_excel_converter\vendor\bin\.phpunit\phpunit-6.5\vendor\ph
  punit\php-code-coverage' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

So there is a problem to install "phpunit/php-code-coverage". 
I really need help to solve this problem ;) I am not an expert regarding
Composer and phpUnit. Up to this point, I had no problems with my Symfony installtion. Thank you.

Comment: Are already tried to  removing from the file system the folder that already exists?

Comment: Yes I removed the folder but with no success. But after I install a new version of symfony 4 and copy all my files this, everything runs fine. So hopefully I do not get this problem again...

Comment: really strange.  You could also try to remove the whole `vendor` folder and retry